# Reload a WPF Window for Consistent UI?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have been an experienced programmer on Asp.Net, where if on-screen data binding changes I could do reload the web-page.

In WPF application:
`MainWindow` I have displayed records in comboxes. User clicks **`Add New`**, I open a new WPF window to add a tuple into DB and returns back to MainWindow.

But data bindings on MainPage are out-dated.

> Should I manually rebind the data for MainWindow Controls?
>
> Is there a way in WPF to rebind all controls on the page?

Comment: I think we need to see some code to help here, are you using MVVM?

Comment: something like `RaisePropertyChange()` ?

Comment: Can you show your xaml code. Using mvvm you can solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Proper binding should take care of those issues for you. Nothing should have to be reloaded.
Mainwindow

```
 ObservableCollection<SomeClass> _mainscreenlist = new ObservableCollection<SomeClass>();
 // populate _mainscreenlist with your objects

 void OpenNewWindow() {
  var window = new YourOtherWindow(_mainscreenlist);
  window.Show();
 }
```

YourOtherWindow

```
private ObservableCollection<SomeClass> _passedlist;
// 
public YourOtherWindow(ObservableCollection<SomeClass> passedlist) {
 _passedlist = passedlist;
}

private void YourAddMethod() {
    // sadly this doesnt work so will with tuples
    // you will need SomeClass to be a class you create an instance of
    var x = new SomeClass();
    // set data on x as appropiate

    // this triggers wpf to update the mainwindow list, without reloading the window
    _passedlist.add(x);
}
```

Xaruth mention INotifyPropertyChanged which has a good example [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Your SomeClass should implement INotifyPropertyChanged so later if one of your items changes the binding will update the changes on screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a proper binding set up then you may need to refresh the items in the combo box manually after adding something to the collection.

```
combobox.Items.Refresh()
```

You should look into MVVM and INotifyPropertyChanged as mentioned above though.